# Chrome Browser: Disable Squared Outline around rounded Select menu?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Squared Outline/Edges (image) I'm trying to remove (Chrome):

[image]

The goal...  (Firefox Browser):

[image]

The CSS:

```
.wide5 {
    width: 28%;
    height:32px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    border: 3px solid #D2D2CD;
    padding: 4px 8px 4px 6px;
    outline:none;
    margin-bottom:4px;
}

.wide5:focus {
    border: 3px solid #00AEEF;
    outline:none;

}
```

The HTML:

```
<select class="wide5">
<option value="1">1 Unit</option>
<option value="2">2 Units</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your HTML/CSS is fine.  Something else is causing that border.  Please create a jsfiddle, I'd like to see it w/ my own eyes.

Comment: Seems fine on my chrome. Though I'm on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-webkit-appearance: none;` on the select menu gives you the desired behavior in chrome .. **but** gets rid of the select arrow .. not sure if you would mind that or not.

Either way I think that's your best best without Javascript .. unless you restyle the `<select>` menu ..